# Git Revert a commit back to staging area

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert

- State1: A file has a value 'A'
- State2: value changed to 'B'
- State3: Git add(put in index/staging area)
- State4: File committed(put in repository)

I want to do a revert to get to State3(put in staging area) or just state2. Effectively deleting the commit. **How can I do it?** I cannot find anything that does this.

These are my findings. **Are they correct?**

- Checkout: revert to State1
- Reset: revert to State1
- Revert: revert to State1

Edit: State3 is optional as State4 does that for you. It is not "put in index" but "edit in index"

Comment: Please read [ask] and show what you have tried. You also combined two steps into one at "State2". First you change the file on disk, then you do a `git add` to put it in the staging area. So "reverting a commit back to staging" is as simple as resetting and doing a `git add` again.

Comment: changed the question to reflect your suggestion. I was confused about that part.